# VS Code debugger not working (by using launch.json) for a django project

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, vscode-debugger

I am having trouble using the debugger in VS code. This is my first time using VS code and I'm following a Django tutorial from VS code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django). By the section 'explore the debugger' I got stuck, because my debugger doesn't seem to work (probably because I did something stupid or didn't do something).

The thing is, I don't get an error message or something but it just keeps running. As the status bar in VS code doesn't change in the color orange, see image (which it should according to the tutorial). [Statusbar while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hx68.png)

My debugger also doesn't seem to stop at the breakpoint, that I have set at line 9.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFVAE.png).

And here it just keeps running [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJKyQ.png)

I tried stopping the debugger and trying it again, but the outcome doesn't change.

My launch.json file is as followed (launch.json):

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And the file on which I want it to run is as followed (views.py):

```
import re
from django.utils.timezone import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, Django!")

def hello_there(request, name):
    now = datetime.now()
    formatted_now = now.strftime("%A, %d %B, %Y at %X")

    # Filter the name argument to letters only using regular expressions. URL arguments
    # can contain arbitrary text, so we restrict to safe characters only.
    match_object = re.match("[a-zA-Z]+", name)

    if match_object:
        clean_name = match_object.group(0)
    else:
        clean_name = "Friend"

    content = "Hello there, " + clean_name + "! It's " + formatted_now
    return HttpResponse(content)
```

Both files (launch.json) and (views.py) came straight from the following tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django

My screen while ´debugging´:
[Screen while debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNiLx.png)

My manage.py file is as followed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'web_project.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the output when I manually run the code (.venv is my virtual environment):
[Output manually run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAUnY.png)

And how the webpage looks like after running the code (this is how it should be. So my code works, but the debugger doesn't. [Webpage output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGZHX.png)

Comment: Can you share your launch.json file too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @VinitaSonakiya I just shared my launch.json file and a views.py file on which I want the debugger to run. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons if debugger is not running. Please check the following settings.

1. root folder should be the folder which contain manage.py
2. select the proper python environment/virtual environment
3. launch.json should be configured properly, check this [url](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django)
4. Check if code running without debug mode or not.

If you still have issue, please share the screen shot of vscode, manage.py file and outout of code when running manually via command "python manage.py runserver"

Comment: I tried checking your given settings, but this didn't fix the problem. So I've shared the screenshots and codes. Thanks for taking the time to help me!